# How to use a UITablecell as a textfield in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

I have a UIViewcontroller with one UITableCell.

I would like the UITableCell to act like a text field, so that a user can click on the cell and enter data (Strings, INT, etc)

How can I achieve this in a way that the cell looks like a cell, and not like a cell with a TextField embedded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply style and position the text the same way you would style a table view label. `UITextField` has a `font` property that you can use.